# UITest failed with : "SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nunit, uitest

I can't use UITest anymore with my xamarin project since the last update of xamarin on the stable channel with Xcode 8.2.

Everytime, when I launch the test, I have an error : "SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no matching element". My test series doesn't change from a long time and works well before...

So I don't know how to correct this problem now...

The stack trace : 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00065] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:965 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.Instruments.GetAutomationTemplatePath () [0x00031] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.Instruments.StartInstrumentsInternal (System.String targetApplication, Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSRunType runType, System.String deviceId, System.String runLoopPath, Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode, System.Predicate`1[T] dropLine) [0x00006] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.Instruments.StartInstruments (System.String targetApplication, Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSRunType runType, System.String deviceId, Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00012] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.RunAppInEmulatorInternal (System.String application, Xamarin.UITest.iOS.Instruments instruments, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Uri deviceUri, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Artifacts.ArtifactFolder artifactFolder, Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode, System.String deviceIdentifier) [0x00095] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.RunAppInEmulator (Xamarin.UITest.Shared.iOS.AppBundle appBundle, Xamarin.UITest.iOS.Instruments instruments, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Uri deviceUri, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Artifacts.ArtifactFolder artifactFolder, Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode, System.String deviceIdentifier) [0x00099] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient) [0x000e4] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x002db] in :0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in :0 
  at Ac.Test.TestV35.BeforeEachTest () [0x00012] in /Users/ShaprAdmin/Documents/ac/Ac.Test/TestV35.cs:17 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to grab the newest Xcode and 
then beside proper NUnit version (2.6.x and proper NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.0)

try do upgrade/downgrade the Xamarin.UITest package to version 2.5.

For me it was not working (with same error) for 2.7 for 2.5 it's ok.

Regards,

Comment: Upgrading Xamarin.UITest did it for me, though I did not find a version higher than 2.2.2. That version fixed the issue however.